# Auto update model value based on another value in this model django

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Products. This model has values like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    producent   = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    stock       = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    display     = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=True)
```

How can I change **display** to be *False* if stock is equal to 0 automatically, so when client buys last product in store display value will change from True to False and

```
Product.objects.filter(display=True)
```

will result in products that I want to show or are in stock.

I know that I can simply chain .filter() but I wonder if I can do in an elegant way

Comment: Why use a `display` field in the first place, and not just filter with `Product.objects.filter(stock__gt=0)`.

Comment: Because sometimes I have product in stock but I want to stop selling it for a period o time

Comment: You can filter with `Product.objects.filter(stock__gt=0, display=True)`. Since you will probably have to do that very often, you can make use of a `Manager` to encapsulate the filtering logic in `Product.objects` for example, and thus do not have to filter explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you said I think you have a view to decrease stock value

Add this logic to your view, after update the stock value:

```
if product.stock==0:
    product.display = False
    product.save()
```

Considering that your view (used to decrease stock value) already instantiated the target "product". If that don't help you, please, post your view.py, to give us more information.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I do have a view that is decreasing stock value when user buys something. I will probably implement that and don't tilt at windmills

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the `display` field: adding logic to set that field will make the server more complicated, and it also means that if later stock is available again, someone has to manually set `display` back to `True`, since you can not know if `display` was set to `False` because you do not want to display the item, or because there was no stock.

You can filter with:

```
Product.objects.filter(display=True, stock__gt=0)
```

Since you probably want to that nearly every time you access objects, you can override the `objects` mananger with a [*custom manager* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-1):

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_querset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            display=True, stock__gt=0
        )

class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = ProductManager()
```

If you now use `Product.objects.all()` for example, it will automatically filter the `Product` items. If you need all the `Product`s, you can work with `Product._base_manager.all()`.